# "Lends way" as an alternative to "lends itself to"

Tags: word-choice

Is "lends way" an accepted alternative to "lends itself to"? I'd imagine the only difference is the former is less formal than the latter.

I was surprised how uncommon "lends way" is:

- google search for "lends way" returns 10,900 results
- google search for "lends itself to" returns over 6 million results
- the [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lends%20way%2Clends%20itself%20to&year_start=1800&year_end=2015&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clends%20itself%20to%3B%2Cc0) doesn't even have data for "lends way"

Am I better off removing it entirely from my lexicon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never heard of "lends way". If you asked me about it I would say is was probably a mishearing of " lends weight", meaning "counts as evidence in favour". For example:

> The proportion of people with higher degrees *lends weight* to the idea that education is highly valued.

Comment: Indeed... I had a feeling it was an eggcorn; I just couldn't figure out the original phrase.

Comment: "The proportion of people with higher degrees [...]" - What an intriguing concept.